# dtd #PCDATA for child nodes in xml

Tags: html, xml, xslt, loops, dtd

I have a few child nodes that repeat. How do I create an internal DTD namespace to make f1 and f2 use #PCDATA?

```
<xsl:for-each select="a/b/c/d/e[1]/f">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="f1"></td>       
          <td><xsl:value-of select="f2">/td> 
          <td>
</xsl:for-each>
<xsl:for-each select="a/b/c/d/e[2]/f">
        <tr>
          <td><xsl:value-of select="f1"></td>       
          <td><xsl:value-of select="f2">/td> 
          <td>
</xsl:for-each>
```

XML:

```
<a>
<b>
<c>
<d>
<e section="1">
<f>
<f1></f1><f2></f2>
</f>
</e>
<e section="2">
<f>
<f1></f1><f2></f2>
</f>
</e>
</d>
</c>
</b>
</a>
```

How do I create an internal DTD namespace to make f1 and f2 use #PCDATA?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appropriate DTD:

```
<!DOCTYPE a [

    <!ELEMENT a (b)>
    <!ELEMENT b (c)>
    <!ELEMENT c (d)>
    <!ELEMENT d (e*)>
    <!ELEMENT e (f)>
    <!ELEMENT f (f1, f2)>
    <!ELEMENT f1 (#PCDATA)>
    <!ELEMENT f2 (#PCDATA)>

    <!ATTLIST e section CDATA #REQUIRED>

]>
```

Comment: Great. But if i only want pcdata for f1 and f2, do i have to specify each element from a thru e?